# How to start a week from Sat instead of Sun

Tags: r, date

I've got a data set with dates and sales, I have to show weekly sales i.e. Sat to Fri would be one week.

```
date=as.Date("2018-03-26")
floor_date(date, unit=week)
```

The above code gives me the start of the week 
i.e. Sunday but I'm looking for Sat rather.
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lubridate::floor_date(date, unit = "week", week_start = getOption("lubridate.week.start", 6))
# [1] "2018-03-24"
```

see the output of `str(floor_date)`

```
function (x, unit = "seconds", week_start = getOption("lubridate.week.start", 7))
```

The default, 7, is Sunday, 6 is Saturday.